# Ajax CDN support for ajaxcontroltoolkit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cdn

I am using ajaxcontroltoolkit in my web forms application. I have added ToolkitScriptManager in my master page like below;

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" />
```

and the following lines are generated;

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=Jibl3MtI-Z0SnbWFojUORizoN9Crh5ry8NMfzJSSnoTf-UFTKFjMJ64T1LoJzsMiy-3x84ZOv4fPul5Ovf0hWqKfvas1&amp;t=634361805716190000" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=GaKMM7fT3pJ-STBLsG7RA9G19YL8-8Qwn55cEa789OnUZnJVo7k-lHiGlv-78SX_-jNa1e8ggtiMU1q11qL5p_Ds-x2fGN94tSQ_LiVmXw5rZT5JLvwPijiZtGc4sjeI6qyDWl6iPDaSvOI5BxUFSYMrocQ1&amp;t=ffffffff88dd8486" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=5-e4xi7M2z7nkjzlbU8-TWOpW3pG-5yWTc1gjU27ASzLUO3z3X6ekk3Sni1yPjhQTHZqsYZzKxrYCi_Gka_qck67rCoY74phG4J0hnrafob5PPfGsqMiXsHm5iwUWoAf11fyGw2&amp;t=11e6618b" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=QuFbQ1DExlSpNLIb-yKHF9rpmtXEsaZy3mY1kUywoGagqJwlk39ehRy6UMfloAvfPq5iKspCQd3hr6z2WtLRfs2vX5cK8IhsLTmXS2C608YECG519GPA63CN6_5IYjb9Or0HIg2&amp;t=11e6618b" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl08_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-GB%3a1547e793-5b7e-48fe-8490-03a375b13a33%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3aca57ef3c%3aab09e3fe" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Is there any way that I can serve them from Ajax CDN? I am on .net 4. thanks!

**EDIT :** 
here how it looks like after I added EnableCdn property;

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebUIValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=5-e4xi7M2z7nkjzlbU8-TWOpW3pG-5yWTc1gjU27ASzLUO3z3X6ekk3Sni1yPjhQTHZqsYZzKxrYCi_Gka_qck67rCoY74phG4J0hnrafob5PPfGsqMiXsHm5iwUWoAf11fyGw2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=QuFbQ1DExlSpNLIb-yKHF9rpmtXEsaZy3mY1kUywoGagqJwlk39ehRy6UMfloAvfPq5iKspCQd3hr6z2WtLRfs2vX5cK8IhsLTmXS2C608YECG519GPA63CN6_5IYjb9Or0HIg2&amp;t=ffffffffbd2983fc" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl08_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-GB%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3aca57ef3c%3aab09e3fe" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the .NET 4 version of the Control Toolkit, simply set `EnableCdn` to true:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" EnableCdn="true" />
```

Comment: There is something like that but It does not converted them. there is something here : http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26841 do you know what it means that 'from AXDs'?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the .NET 4 version of the AJAX Control Toolkit? You can [get it here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/63654).

Comment: I am. I just downloaded it via nuget. Also I can get itelisense for EnableCnd property so it must be legit. only validation js files has been converted for cdn. please see the new view of my source on my question edit section.

Comment: Do take [a look at this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/11/23/asp-net-4-0-scriptmanager-improvements.aspx) for some ideas on getting around this.

Comment: this is a great article but there are a lot of info inside it. couldn't find the proper info for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, the control points to local dynamic files only.
Maybe a better idea is migrate the functions used, to a jquery based alternative with witch you can use a CDN.